# rails generate scaffold with --migration=false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a very large model (say 200 fields), so it isn't very convenient to write them down into the command line. 
So I first generate the migration then i did scaffold with:

```
rails generate scaffold myModel --migrate=false
```

It generated the controller with its actions, it updated the routes.rb and created views/myModel. 
But it didn't add the fields to the views. Isn't scaffold supposed to provide a basic field presentation? If not, is there a way to provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffold uses the command line arguments you specify to create the relevant files.  If you don't specify any fields at the command line then it can't add them to the views (because it doesn't know them).  The Scaffold command is a one time thing.  You might consider typing out and/or programmatically creating the relevant scaffold command in a text editor and pasting it into the console.

Comment: thanks for your answer, olleicua. you confirmed to me what i suspected. i think that this feature of the scaffolding is very basic and i think it needs to be enhanced. ok, it doesn't know the fields but it could know them if it wanted to. because they are well written in the model. the fact that it is a "one time thing" all the more so, because it eliminates the case of handlig just a part of the fields: when you call scaffolding, it should manage all the fields present in that moment in the model.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to call the scaffold command after creating the model.  I'm a little confused though.  Rails models don't need to list all of the fields in the db.  Are you wanting it to list the methods defined in the model as fields..?

Comment: Infact i was trying to create the fields in the view, not in the model where they are "implicitly" created

Comment: I'm still confused.  You have to tell rails what fields you want somewhere.  Where are you defining these fields.

Comment: In the migration, that normally is the first thing I do. Did I say the model? Yes, i did. I meant the migration.

Comment: Oh! that makes way more sense.  Yeah that would be a cool thing if it worked.  It probably wouldn't be too hard to write a script that reads the columns from db/schema.rb and uses them to generate a scaffold command.